# SQL: How to create new columns depending on other column's value in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have 2 tables, Main and Units.

Main table:

```
Todate   Unit   CategoryID   Quantity
1/7/2012  1        S            300
1/7/2012  1        U            350
2/7/2012  2        S            220
3/7/2012  2        S             50
3/7/2012  2        U            330
4/7/2012  1        S            200
4/7/2012  1        U            180
```

S = Sales, U = Upgrades

Units table:

```
UnitNum   UnitName
1         Measures
2         Performance
```

I need to get this result:

```
Todate   UnitNum   UnitName    Sales    Upgrades
1/7/2012    1      Measures     300       350
2/7/2012    2      Performance  220
3/7/2012    2      Performance   50       330
4/7/2012    1      Measures     200       180
```

Meaning i need to create 2 columns - sales and upgrades, depending on the value in CategoryID, and i need them to be in the same row.
What i have so far is this

```
select Todate, Main.Unit, UnitName,
case when CategoryID = 'S' then Quantity end as Sales,
case when CategoryID = 'U' then Quantity end as Upgrades
from Main join Units on Main.UnitNum = Units.UnitNum
group by  Todate, Main.Unit, UnitName
```

It gives me 2 new columns but they are in two separate rows..

I would really appreciate any help resolving this!
Thank you

Comment: I really recommend you to use primary indexes (uniques) for catgories. Instead of U and S make one other table named categories which will contains Sales and Upgrades and in the main table store the primary id of each row in categories.

Comment: Matei Mihai, i didn't create this, it's just a question that i was asked and couldn't answer

Comment: Is there a case that could be 2 (or more) rows with same `Todate`, same `Unit` and same `CategoryID`?

Comment: Have you tried to JOIN the main table with itself based on todate and unitnum, and then retrieve only distinct rows? I'm on my smartphone right now, but I cannot cook up an example tomorrow, if you haven't figured something out.

Comment: ypercube, i guess it can be, i'm not sure whether there are any keys in this table. But in such case the quantities of those rows with identical date, unit and category should be summed and appear in one line

Answer (score 1):

You just need an aggregate query around the `case` statements.

```
select m.todate
     , m.unit
     , u.unitname
     , sum(case when m.categoryid = 'S' then quantity end ) as sales
     , sum(case when m.categoryid = 'U' then quantity end ) as upgrages
  from main m
  join units u
    on m.unit = u.unitnum
 group by m.todate, m.unit, u.unitname
```

Comment: hmm, you're right this won't give the expected results but only because you seem to have selected a random `unitname`. This implies that you should put an aggregate query around this column as well and remove it from the `group by` but there's no obvious reason for the one you chose in your expected result set. Why are they as expected?

Comment: Do you mean that UnitName doesn't have to appear in result set? That was the expected result set, i just copied the question as it was

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT
    Todate, m.Unit, UnitName,
    Sales = (SELECT SUM(Quantity)
             FROM dbo.Main m2 
             WHERE m.Todate = m2.Todate AND CategoryID = 'S'),
    Updates = (SELECT SUM(Quantity)
               FROM dbo.Main m2 
               WHERE m.Todate = m2.Todate AND CategoryID = 'U')
FROM
    dbo.Main m 
INNER join 
    dbo.Units u on m.Unit = u.UnitNum
GROUP BY  
    Todate, m.Unit, UnitName
ORDER BY  
    Todate, m.Unit, UnitName
```

This seems to be returning the output you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: It seems really close, but what if i add another row where the unit is null, for example: 4/7/2012, null, S, 15. It should be added as another row, but your code adds this to the sum of the last row and i get 2012-04-07  1  Measures  215  180

Comment: @Cat: what did you expect when you add this row?? It will be added to (1) the `Todate` given (4/7/2012), and to the Sales or Updates column depending on the `CategoryID` - but you didn't make it clear in your question how the `Unit` is relevant here..... what **should** happen to a row `(4/7/2012, NULL, 'S', 15)`  ?? SHould it be added to the sum? Or ignored? Or what else?

Comment: I'm sorry i wasn't clear from the start. If unit is not specified, it shouldn't be added to the sum of another row, it should be added as another row. I was asked this question in an interview and i don't know specific rules, i'm just going by the expected result that i was given. There "unitless" row was shown as a row on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a self-join of your main table with itself:

```
 SELECT m1.todate, m1.unit AS unitnum, u.unitname,
        SUM(m1.quantity) AS sales, SUM(m2.quantity) AS upgrades
   FROM (SELECT todate, unit, quantity FROM Main WHERE category = 'S') AS m1
   FULL OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT todate, unit, quantity FROM Main WHERE category = 'U') AS m2
     ON m1.todate = m2.todate AND m1.unit = m2.unit
   JOIN units AS u
     ON m1.unit = u.unitnum
  GROUP BY m1.todate, m1.unit, u.unitname
  ORDER BY m1.todate, m1.unit, u.unitname;
```

There are many other equivalent ways of writing the same query; this one preserves the symmetry of the problem fairly well, though.  (*Updated to use a FULL OUTER JOIN between the `m1` and `m2` sub-queries, to deal with cases where there are sales with no upgrades or upgrades with no sales.*)

Comment: This version ignores the line where i have only Sales (2/7/2012 2 220), it doesn't appear in the result. Also, if i add rows without unit number, it ignores them completely

Comment: What would you be doing with incomplete rows without a unit number?  Dealing with the other issue is a nuisance — you need a FULL OUTER JOIN (assuming that you could have sales only or upgrades only on any given day).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) for this too:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    m.Todate,
    m.UnitNum,
    u.UnitName,
    Category = CASE m.CategoryID
                 WHEN 'S' THEN 'Sales'
                 WHEN 'U' THEN 'Upgrades'
               END,
    Quantity
  FROM Main m
  INNER JOIN Units u
  ON m.UnitNum = u.UnitNum
)
SELECT
  Todate,
  UnitNum,
  UnitName,
  Sales,
  Upgrades
FROM data
PIVOT (
  SUM(Quantity) FOR Category IN (Sales, Upgrades)
) p
;
```